# Brown pods from tree like Carob okay to eat raw?

Tags: food-safety, food-identification

Trees near my house have these pods covering the ground, by the side of the street. They look like Carob to me. I took a few of them.

Searching Google, I don't see other trees that grow long brown pods matching these.

Are these Carob pods and can I eat them as is? Are there other factors to consider? Maybe they're contaminated from being next to the street or infected with pathogens from lying on the ground? Or perhaps they're too old to eat? I don't know if these are potential issues.

I already bit a small piece and it did taste like chocolate.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is attempting to ascertain that whether a plant is edible or not, which is off topic. We are not plant specialists.

Comment: For more info on this topic, see [this](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/2126/33128) meta discussion.

Comment: Yes, please delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show a picture of the tree but those appear to be pods from a honey locust tree. The tree usually has thorns growing on its trunk. I've never heard of them being edible but I did find some info here: [maybe but probably not best idea.](https://permies.com/t/1664/edibility-honey-locust-leaves-pods)Young fruits may be more edible.

Comment: It's not honey locust. It's carob and I've been eating it.